Infinitely many solutions to a polynomial equation in 3-adic integers?
I am learning about $p$-adic integers and numbers, and I stumbled upon this Stack Exchange post: Finding number of roots of a polynomial in p-adic integers $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ on the number of roots of the polynomial $X^3 + 25X^2 + X - 9$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for several $p$.
I have a rather specific question that I am unable to resolve. In the answer, it is said that there are infinitely many roots when $p = 3$. I understand the explanation using Hensel's Lemma. However, is it not true that $\mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}_3 \subseteq \mathbb{Q}_3$? By abstract algebra, we have $X^3 + 25X^2 + X - 9 \in \mathbb{Q}_3[X] \setminus \{0\}$ and so there can be at most $\text{deg}(X^3 + 25X^2 + X - 9) = 3$ roots in $\mathbb{Q}_3$? How can a nonzero polynomial over a field have infinitely many roots? This feels like a contradiction.
Thanks a lot in advance!

I think you're correct and the answer there is wrong.  According to my calculations, there are exactly three roots in $\mathbb{Z}_3$, which are ...0011221, ...1112211, ...1020100 in base 3.

The discriminant of the given polynomial is $556884 = 2^2 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 31 \cdot 499$, so there are potentially similar issues for $p=2, 3, 31, 499$.

I agree with @DanielSchepler that the answer is probably wrong. I haven't figured out the exact mistake, but there do seem to be some leaps of logic (eg "you will always have three solutions", "the third produces three fresh solutions") that don't have any proof offered.

I just posted a new answer on the linked question which does a correct calculation for $p=3$.

You are right that in any integral domain, a polynomial of degree $n$ can have at most $n$ solutions.

Many thanks for the responses gentlemen! I did not expect to be correct there ^^

Alternatively to the field argument, Hensel's lemma can be pushed further to prove uniqueness with a bound based on the derivative. For succinctness of this comment, an alternate way of phrasing Hensel's lemma with the $p$-adic absolute value $|\cdot|$ is that if you can find some $a$ such that $|f(a)|<|f'(a)|^2$, then there is some root $r$ that satisfies $f(r)=0$ which is uniquely contained in the "open" ball centered at $a$ of radius $|f'(a)|$. In other words for all $x$ that satisfy $|x-a|<|f'(a)|$, that $r$ is unique.
